# Draw text to image change bug

Tags: c#

I want to create program that draws text on image. For that purpose I used this method:

```
private static Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
    //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
    Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    //create a new image of the right size
    img = new Bitmap((int)textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(backColor);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;

}
```

My problem is that I want to draw table in the image, so the table should look like:
[image]

I used this [library](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/ConsoleTables) for drawing table
And code looks like this method from above

```
    var table = new ConsoleTable("one", "two", "three")
                 .AddRow("random text';", "random text", "random text")
                 .Configure(o => o.NumberAlignment = Alignment.Left)
                 .ToString();

DrawText(table, new Font("Verdana", 20), Color.Black, Color.White);
```

And i got this kind of image
[image]

Rows are really changed and it doesn't look like table above. I think method `DrawText` changed something but I don't know what exactly it is? So I need help. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: It probably has to do with you drawing it with Verdana. Verdana isn't monospaced so your alignment isn't "guaranteed" like it is when you create that table.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb what font should i use?

Comment: Try Consolas !!

Comment: If you really need to draw a table into an image, you can use whatever font you like, but you have to calculate each column's width based on _all_ of the text in that column, and each row's height based on _all_ of the text in that row. See first duplicate. If you are doing this in Winforms and just need to display a table, use `DataGridView` (other duplicate). Of course, you can kludge the result by using a monospaced font, but that doesn't fix the underlying problem with your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *need* Verdana (which isn't a monospaced font), you should be able to fix this by slightly altering your call to `DrawText` like so:

```
DrawText(table, new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 20), Color.Black, Color.White);
```

I'm not actually super familiar with working with fonts, so using `FontFamily.GenericMonospace` is sort of my best guess. You should be able to use others though. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) has a list of them.